# Calculate area of circle, triangle and cylinder in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program that should calculate the area of circles, triangles and cylinders. I made it but for some reason it does not run and I am unable to find any bugs in my code and I need help with it. Can someone please explain me why the following code does not work? Appreciate it.

```cs
using System;
using static System.Console;

class Program {
 static void Main() {
  int choice = 0;
  Console.WriteLine("[1]Area of circle");
  Console.WriteLine("[2]Area of rectangle");
  Console.WriteLine("[3]Area of cylander");
  choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  if (choice = "1") {
   CirArea();
   Another();
  }
  if (choice = "2") {
   TriArea();
   Another();
  } else
   CylArea();
  Another();
 }
 private static void CirArea() {
  double cirarea;
  double radius;
  double pi = 3.14;
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
  radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  cirarea = pi * Math.Sqrt(radius);
  Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is +cirarea");
 }
 private static void TriArea() {
  double triarea;
  double length;
  double width;
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
  length = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
  width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  triarea = length * width;
  Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle is +triarea.");
 }
 private static void CylArea() {
  double cylarea;
  double radius;
  double height;
  double pi = 3.14;
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius of cylinder: ");
  radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height of the cylinder: ");
  height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  cylarea = 2 * pi * radius * height + 2 * pi * Math.Sqrt(radius);
  Console.WriteLine("The area of the cylinder is +cylarea");
 }
 private static void Another() {
  string answer;
  Console.WriteLine("Do you want to get another calculation?[Y/N]");
  answer = Console.ReadLine();
  if (answer = "Y" || "y") {
   int choice = 0;
   Console.WriteLine("[1]Area of circle");
   Console.WriteLine("[2]Area of rectangle");
   Console.WriteLine("[3]Area of cylander");
   choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  } else {
   Console.WriteLine("You can now close this program.");
  }
 }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Clarify what exactly it says when you try to run/compile it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework.  Ask your instructor.  Teachers *need* to hear from their students in order to know when something might need more discussion at the next classroom session.  "We can't read your minds ..."

Comment: It's an online course so the teacher is not available most of the time. Thank you everyone for the answers I will try them

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;

namespace figurearea
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string choice = "";
            Console.WriteLine("[1]Area of circle");
            Console.WriteLine("[2]Area of rectangle");
            Console.WriteLine("[3]Area of cylander");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if (choice == "1")
            {
                CirArea();
                Another();
            }
            else if (choice == "2")
            {
                TriArea();
                Another();
            }
            else if (choice == "3")
                CylArea();
            Another();
        }
        private static void CirArea()
        {
            double cirarea;
            double radius;
            double pi = 3.14;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius of the circle :");
            radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            cirarea = pi * Math.Sqrt(radius);
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is :"+ cirarea);
        }
        private static void TriArea()
        {
            double triarea;
            double length;
            double width;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            length = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the width of the rectangle: ");
            width = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            triarea = length * width;
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle is :" + triarea);
        }
        private static void CylArea()
        {
            double cylarea;
            double radius;
            double height;
            double pi = 3.14;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the radius of cylinder: ");
            radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the height of the cylinder: ");
            height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            cylarea = 2 * pi * radius * height + 2 * pi * Math.Sqrt(radius);
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the cylinder is :"+ cylarea);
        }
        private static void Another()
        {
            string answer;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to get another calculation?[Y/N]");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer.Equals("Y",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                int choice = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("[1]Area of circle");
                Console.WriteLine("[2]Area of rectangle");
                Console.WriteLine("[3]Area of cylander");
                choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You can now close this program.");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Could you add some explanations as to how/why this fixes the stated question.

Answer (score 0):

The equals operator is '==' not '='. Change if (choice = "1") to if (choice == 1) and so on with 2 and 3. Hope that helps a little bit!